# Detect row index on click of dropdown list in html using java script

Tags: javascript, html

There is JSP page , in which user has to select item name then depending upon item choose , related data which is store in value field of drop down list will be add to next column of similar row and table.

My question is how we can detect that which row's drop-down list selected?

I also used a add row function to add new to table and also change id of drop-down list. But this code fails when any row is deleted because sequence broken . So suggest me what can i do in  this situation.

Code of java script file is attached:

```
function addRow(tableID)
{
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    if (i == 0) {
        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
    }
    else if (i == 1) {
        newcell.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;
        newcell.childNodes[0].value = rowCount + 1;
    }
    else if (i == 2) {
        var res = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        alert(res);
        var str_new = "";
        var new_no = rowCount;
        var str = "read('" + new_no + "')";
        str_new = res.replace("read('0')", str);
        newcell.innerHTML = str_new;
        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
    }
    else if (i == 3) {
        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
    }
    else if (i == 4) {
        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
    }
    else if (i == 5) {
        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
    }
    else if (i == 6) {
        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
    }

   }
}
function deleteRow(tableID) {
try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            if (rowCount <= 1) {
                alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                break;
            }
            table.deleteRow(i);
            rowCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
resetSrNo(tableID);
}
function resetSrNo(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
for (var i =0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = i + 1;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you put working example ?

Comment: Removed the Java tag as the fact that this is JSP is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: It sounds like the jQuery tag is unrelevant too...

Comment: If you attach an event to handle the change event of the `<select>` elements by using `.addEventListener`, the `this` variable inside that function will point to the the clicked `<select>` element. From there, you can get the parent of the select element and, if that is a `<td>`, the parent of _that_ will be the containing row. I.e assuming a row like the following: `<tr><td>blah</td><td><select><option>Select one</option></td></tr>`, you can get the row like so from within an attached event. `var selElem = this; var td = selElem.parentNode; var containingRow = td.parentNode;` :)